# Split swagger doc to separate sets

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger with .net core and I'm wondering if it is possible to split 2 or more sets of swagger docs that is accessible via different urls.
Not talking about versioning here.

Take for example if I have API that is for mobile app, web app, another for my clients.
I want to separate them out respectively and also add authorization for mobile and web api only, but not client.
I have this idea to separate the respective api to areas but I still have no idea how to split it for the swagger docs.

Only way I know I can get the same result is by splitting it to separate projects.

Any other ideas to go around this are very much welcomed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the possibilities (and not best) is to write specifications by hand, cuz it is just a JSON file.

The second one is using this example: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents

Word "version" means not only different versions of the same API but "client api", "webapi" and so on.

Comment: Thanks, finally got it to work. 
One of the key part was the invocation of DocInclusionPredicate part.

Comment: Can you provide info about how did you achieve this ?

Comment: The provided link was very useful.

Comment: @BurakDobur Navigate to the link and read these three titles: (1) Generate Multiple Swagger Documents, (2) Customize the Action Selection Process, and (3) List Multiple Swagger Documents